# Flutter Zoom image inside container

Tags: flutter, dart, gesture

I can use the Interactive Viewer to zoom the image inside the Container.
However, it seems that the scale of the image is changing, not that the image is enlarged inside the container.

Do you know how to zoom the image without going out of the container's area?

```
Container(
        width: this.size!.width,
        height: this.size!.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
        ),
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          panEnabled: true,
          minScale: 1.0,
          maxScale: 3.0,
          onInteractionStart: (details) {
            if (details.pointerCount < 2) return;
          },
          onInteractionUpdate: (details) {
            details.focalPoint;
          },
          child: GestureDetector(
            onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
              if (details.primaryVelocity! > 0) {
                context
                    .read<ServerCommunicationProvider>()
                    .decrementPageIndex();
              } else if (details.primaryVelocity! < 0) {
                context
                    .read<ServerCommunicationProvider>()
                    .incrementPageIndex();
              }
            },
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage(
                  context.watch<ServerCommunicationProvider>().imagePath[
                      context.watch<ServerCommunicationProvider>().nPageIndex]),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I solved this using 'photo_view'. I've attached the source that fixed the problem below.

```
      child: Container(
        width: this.size!.width,
        height: this.size!.height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
        ),
        child: GestureDetector(
            onHorizontalDragEnd: (DragEndDetails details) {
              if (details.primaryVelocity! > 0) {
                context.read<ServerCommunicationProvider>()
                    .decrementPageIndex();
              } else if (details.primaryVelocity! < 0) {
                context.read<ServerCommunicationProvider>()
                    .incrementPageIndex();
              }
            },
            child: ClipRect(
              child: PhotoView(
                imageProvider: AssetImage('${context
                    .watch<ServerCommunicationProvider>()
                    .imagePath[
                context
                    .watch<ServerCommunicationProvider>()
                    .nPageIndex
                ]}'),
                maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 2.0,
                minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
                initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
              ),
            ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Why don't you try [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view) plugin, this makes your task easier.

Comment: I used `photo_view` but it's the same. I have implemented `borders` using borders on Containers. As the size of the image increases, the image grows outside the border. I want it to `zoom` within the `border`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [photo_view](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view)

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: PhotoView(
      imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/large-image.jpg"),
    )
  );
}
```

if you use `photoViewGallery` it will contain the image into the `container`.

first import

```
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view_gallery.dart';
```

Usage of PhotoViewGallery

```
        AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: 1,
            child: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
              backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
              scrollPhysics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
                  maxScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
                  minScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
                  imageProvider: AssetImage(
                      "assets/images/backgrounds/courses_congrats.png"),
                  initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained,
                );
              },
              itemCount: 1,
            ),
          )
```

Comment: I used `photo_view` but it's the same. I have implemented borders using `borders` on Containers. As the size of the image increases, the image grows outside the border. I want it to `zoom` within the `border`.